# NSXMLParser parsing interrupted in the middle of the XML document

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm parsing a complicated multi-element XML file, so far so good. The main issue that I got now it's that parser doesn't go across the whole file, it stops for some reason about the middle of the XML file.

It seems properly written to me, but NOTE this, if I make the document shorter, then it goes to the end flawlessly.

It isn't a huge file, I'm talking about 100 lines of code Vs 50.

I'm just printing the elements, doing nothing actually... it just doesn't get it all.

Any clue? Why this behaviour?

Thank you all very much!

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    NSLog(@"Element found: %@", elementName);

    for (NSString *str in attributeDict) {
        NSLog(@"Attributes: %@ %@", str, [attributeDict objectForKey:str]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You say it "seems" property written. Verify that it is. Validate it using some online XML validation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something wrong with your XML Helen Wood, please check your XML with link below :

http://www.xmlvalidation.com

let me know if you find solution.

Comment: Helen Wood did you fix your problem?

Comment: I didn't but it seems the XML was corrupted in some point... Thank you.